# Is there a way to call a specific function automatically when calling transaction commit in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to ensure that a specific function is always called at the end of a transaction, just before commit. Is there a way to have postgres do this automatically without a client having to execute anything other than commit?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: You can do that, but you have to write C code for that. I can give you details if you are interested in that kind of solution.